# Error during sync: googleapi: Error 400: while configuring ingress for Kubernetes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following ingress configuration:

I have the following ingress configuration:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "dev-ingress"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: mydomain-net-tls
      hosts: 
        - mydomain.net
    - secretName: mydomain-me-tls
      hosts:
        - mydomain.me
  rules:
    - host: something.mydomain.net
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: myservice-dev-service
            servicePort: mainnet
```

And the service is as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myservice-dev-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-node
  ports:
  - name: mainnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3001
```

I haven't configured any `livenessprobe` for the deployment and the `readinessprobe` is configured with the following values

```
readinessProbe: 
          httpGet:
              path: /somepath/status
              port: 3001
          initialDelaySeconds: 120 #wait this period after staring fist time
          periodSeconds: 300    # polling interval every 5 minutes
          timeoutSeconds: 60
```

It was running fine earlier, however now I get the following error:

```
Error during sync: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.checkIntervalSec': '360'. Must be less than or equal to 300, invalid
```

What does `resource.checkIntervalSec` stand for and what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably your health check probe, as`checkIntervalSec` is the time interval between checks by default is 5 seconds but the value can be from 1 to 300 Maximun, you set your `periodSeconds: 300` and `timeoutSeconds: 60` both will represent your check interval in second.

you need to lower your `periodSeconds` to `240` if you want to use the maximum interval second allowed.